# Imacro script gives "error code -910" in firefox

Tags: firefox, imacros

I got this macro from a friend that is supposed to open four tabs of chaturbate website and runs for few minutes. I tried running it but its giving this error:

> MacroSyntaxError: wrong format of SET command, line 4 (Error code: -910)

```
VERSION BUILD=6060703 RECORDER=CR
SET !TIMEOUT 300
URL GOTO=http://pt.chaturbate.com/female-cams/
SET !VAR1 EVAL(“var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*20 + 1);randomNumber;”)
TAG POS={{!VAR1}} TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://cdn-i.highwebmedia.com/roomimage/*
Tab OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO=http://pt.chaturbate.com/female-cams/
SET !VAR1 EVAL(“var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*20 + 1); randomNumber;”)
TAG POS={{!VAR1}} TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://cdn-i.highwebmedia.com/roomimage/*
Tab OPEN
TAB T=3
URL GOTO=http://pt.chaturbate.com/female-cams/
SET !VAR1 EVAL(“var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*20 + 1); randomNumber;”)
TAG POS={{!VAR1}} TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://cdn-i.highwebmedia.com/roomimage/*
Tab OPEN
TAB T=4
URL GOTO=http://pt.chaturbate.com/female-cams/
SET !VAR1 EVAL(“var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 1); randomNumber;”)
TAG POS={{!VAR1}} TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://cdn-i.highwebmedia.com/roomimage/*
WAIT SECONDS =630

Tab CLOSEALLOTHERS
```

Any help would be appreciated.